# How to link to node_modules folder with Laravel mix

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I'm using the Metronic theme and installed the packages with npm and now a bunch of what I need is in the node_modules folder.

How do I link to these in laravel mix?

Ive tried googling and reading the laravel mix documentation however kind of stuck on this.

Answer (score 3):

The documentation seems to explain how to import (.js and .css) and copy assets (images etc..)

[Working With JavaScript](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/mix#working-with-scripts): You could amend the example to something like `mix.js('node_modules/metronic/src/js/framework/components/general/menu.js', 'public/js');`

[Working With Stylesheets](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/mix#working-with-stylesheets): Amend this example to something like  `mix.sass('node_modules/metronic/src/sass/framework/_config.scss', 'public/css');`

[Copying Files & Directories](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/mix#copying-files-and-directories): Directly from the example `mix.copy('node_modules/foo/bar.css', 'public/css/bar.css');`

*please note the `node_modules/metronic/` path is my best guess*

Comment: Thanks, do I just reference every file that the theme wants in this list?

Comment: You shouldn't have to. The main file should have references to the other modules so you just have to import one. Usually the entry point is `index.js`. However if you just want only specific modules, then you have to import them individually. This will be same for SASS files